# Killing Two different Processes With VB

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to figure out how to kill two processes at the same time I have managed to get one to work when it is opened but the other wont close.

```
  Sub block()
    For Each item As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If item.ProcessName = "taskmgr" And item.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
            item.Kill()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your logic is in error. If the Process name is taskmgr AND cmd. That will never be true. And the exe is part of the name.

Comment: `If item.ProcessName = "taskmgr" OrElse item.ProcessName = "cmd"` that will work. The condition can't be for both, it's either one or the other...

Comment: Another option is to create a watcher `System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher` which would prevent them from even starting instead of checking for them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Noodles and @Zaggler your logic is wrong on this line;

```
  If item.ProcessName = "taskmgr" And item.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
```

This line essentially asks if the process name is "taskmgr" and if the same process name is "cmd". Since these two strings aren't the same "taskmgr" /= "cmd" this if clause will never be true. I suggest you do something like this;

```
Sub block()
  For Each item As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If item.ProcessName = "taskmgr" Then
        item.Kill()
    ElseIf item.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
        item.Kill()
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Or optionally if you plan to close many processes;

```
'declare at form loading or elsewhere
Dim proclist as new list (of string)
proclist.add("taskmgr")
proclist.add("cmd")
proclist.add("...")

Sub block()
  For Each item As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If proclist.contains(item.ProcessName)  Then
        item.Kill()
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Whoever left the random downvote - please give me some feedback so I can improve on whatever the problem was, thanks!

Comment: Rather late reply... I didn't cast that downvote, however I think it might be related to the fact that you created a whole `ElseIf`-statement rather than just switching `And` to `OrElse`.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with this solution in vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,fso,MainArray,LogFile,i,OutPut,count
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MainArray = Array("taskmgr.exe","cmd.exe")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "log"
count = 0 
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then fso.DeleteFile LogFile
Set OutPut = fso.OpenTextFile(LogFile,2,True)
For i = LBound(MainArray) To UBound(MainArray)
    Call Kill(MainArray(i))
Next
OutPut.WriteLine String(50,"*") 
OutPut.WriteLine count & " Process were killed !"
OutPut.WriteLine String(50,"*")
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then
    ws.run DblQuote(LogFile) 'To show the LogFile
End if
'******************************************
Sub Kill(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like '%" & wsh.scriptname & "%'",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        count= count + 1
        OutPut.WriteLine Mid(objItem.CommandLine,InStr(objItem.CommandLine,""" """) + 2)
        objItem.Terminate(0)
    Next
End Sub
'***********************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***********************************************
```

Comment: That is overkill to kill a process and introducing a VB script is not what the OP is working with and asked for. Although an alternative. Would you mind explaining what the script is doing so other get an understanding what it's doing as there's no detail about it?